# 'arecord' generating blank files with size 44kb

Tags: alsa

> Linux c6a811x-evm 2.6.37 #1 Sat May 7 16:05:26 IST 2016 armv7l unknown

The output of `arecord -l`

```
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 0: EVM [TI81XX EVM], device 0: AIC3X tlv320aic3x-hifi-0 []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

The screen-shot of `alsamixer` I am linking:

[image]

The command I am executing is `arecord -d15 au.wav`.

When i try to run the command
arecord -r 48000 -c 2 -f S16_LE -t
 wav -vv -d 25 example.wav

I am getting the following output after `arecord` command executes in terminal:

[image]

input/output error